# Returning a C function to its grandfather

Tags: c, gdb, x86-64, callstack

This is a homework assignment, so I'd appreciate it if I would get a hint only, not a full answer. I wrote this program which is supposed to print the following:

```
Executing function_a
Executing function_b
Finished!
```

The `main()` and `function_a()` functions were given, and I'm only allowed to change `function_b()` in the marked part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void function_b(void) {
    char buffer[4];

    // edit between here...
    uint32_t * x = &buffer;
    while (*(x++) != 0xa0b1c2d3);           // Find the beacon
    *(uint32_t*)(&buffer + 6) = *(x + 2);   // Copy return address from caller
    *(uint32_t*)(&buffer + 5) = *(x + 1);   // Copy frame pointer from caller
    // ... and here

    fprintf(stdout, "Executing function_b\n");
}

void function_a(void) {
    int beacon = 0xa0b1c2d3;
    fprintf(stdout, "Executing function_a\n");
    function_b();
    fprintf(stdout, "Executed function_b\n");
}

int main(void) {
    function_a();
    fprintf(stdout, "Finished!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is of course to make sure that 'Executed function_b' is not outputted. We have to manipulate the stack so that when returning from `function_b()` we don't go back to its actual parent `function_a()` but to its grandfather `main()`.

The part of the code I wrote finds the beacon from `function_a()` and then copies the return address and saved frame pointer of `function_a()` to the frame of `function_b()`. My program does the following:

```
Executing function_a
Executing function_b
Finished!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So it does the right thing, except for the segfault. It fails when returning from the `main()` function. I used gdb to get this:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /.../exercise2c
Executing function_a

Breakpoint 1, function_b () at exercise2c.c:9
9       *(uint32_t*)(&buffer + 6) = *(x + 2);   // Copy return address from caller
(gdb) backtrace
#0  function_b () at exercise2c.c:9
#1  0x0000000000400607 in function_a () at exercise2c.c:18
#2  0x0000000000400630 in main () at exercise2c.c:23
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffdcb0:
 rip = 0x400593 in function_b (exercise2c.c:9); saved rip = 0x400607
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffdcd0
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffdca0, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffdca0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdcb0
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffdca0, rip at 0x7fffffffdca8
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0000000000400607 in function_a () at exercise2c.c:18
18      function_b();
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 1, frame at 0x7fffffffdcd0:
 rip = 0x400607 in function_a (exercise2c.c:18); saved rip = 0x400630
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffdce0, caller of frame at 0x7fffffffdcb0
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffdcc0, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffdcc0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdcd0
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffdcc0, rip at 0x7fffffffdcc8
(gdb) step
10      *(uint32_t*)(&buffer + 5) = *(x + 1);   // Copy frame pointer from caller
(gdb) step
12      fprintf(stdout, "Executing function_b\n");
(gdb) frame 0
#0  function_b () at exercise2c.c:12
12      fprintf(stdout, "Executing function_b\n");
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffdcb0:
 rip = 0x4005b5 in function_b (exercise2c.c:12); saved rip = 0x400630
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffdcd0
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffdca0, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffdca0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdcb0
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffdca0, rip at 0x7fffffffdca8
(gdb) backtrace
#0  function_b () at exercise2c.c:12
#1  0x0000000000400630 in main () at exercise2c.c:23
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Executing function_b
Finished!

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400654 in main () at exercise2c.c:26
26  }(gdb) 
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

You can clearly see that `function_b()` indeed returns to `main()`, but for some reason that I don't understand `main()` crashes. The only way I could see that happen is that I messed with the stack frame of `main()`, which I didn't, or that I should have changed something there - but I wouldn't know what.

What's going on here?

Note: the program is compiled with GCC and the flags `-g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector`. I'm on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason writes, I should use 64-bit pointers. Besides that, it also turns out that I had to copy four numbers from the stack frame. This is working code:

```
uint64_t * my_ptr = &buf;
int * x = my_ptr;

while (*(++x)  != 0xa0b1c2d3);  // Find the beacon. We could of course simply have a look
uint64_t * y = x + 1;           // with gdb where it's stored, but this works generically.

*(my_ptr+7) = *(y+3);           // Copy frame information
*(my_ptr+6) = *(y+2);
*(my_ptr+5) = *(y+1);
*(my_ptr+4) = *y;
```

Typically you need to fiddle a bit with what addresses you have to copy. You can get a rough idea using gdb, as you did. The exact numbers depend on the functions and their variables.

Comment: "I'd appreciate it if I would get a hint only, not a full answer" -- Yet you accepted your non-hint full-answer as the accepted response :\

Comment: I thought we agreed that I would edit my working code in, in the comments. Yet you rolled back my edit without explanation.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm on a 64-bit machine.

Your code in `function_b()` treats pointers as 32-bit values instead of 64-bit values. You should be using `uint64_t*` instead of `uint32_t*`.